# Time derivative of a fourier transformed signal

Tags: python, derivative

I am working on ecg signals on python and wish to capture the oscillatory behaviour of ecg signals from the parameters- natural frequency, damping factor and input signal, which are in turn extracted from semantic mining. This algorithm uses fourth time derivatives at single point, denoted as x’, x’’, x’’’ and x’’’’ where x is my fourier-transformed ecg signal. My question is how do I take the time derivative of a signal in frequency domain? And to do this which function in python should I use like scipy.misc.derivative or numpy.diff?

Comment: Do you have a function or an array? I guess you have an array and so, you need numpy.diff.

Comment: I actually used numpy.diff on my fft array. But then again I have to perform mathematical operations on(multiply,divide, etc..) these derivatives array and then take a square root of it. So for numpy.sqrt I get a runtime warning saying Runtimewarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt..and when I take a cmath.sqrt, I dont get the expected value..